# chrome Extension Development, JS issue.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Okay so I'm a JS noob, and I can admit that. I've been reading up and learning how to make extensions for chrome. So I want to have a content script and browser action, but I can't get it to run for the life of me. It's probably something dumb I'm doing something wrong, but any help is appreciated.

```
    {
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "*********",
"version": "0.3",
"description": "*****************************",
"icons": { "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png" },
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": {
    "19": "icons/19x19.png",
    "38": "icons/38x38.png"
},
"default_title": "That's the tool tip",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}
"content_scripts": 
[
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"], 
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"  
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Describe what you are trying to achieve and what you observe.

Comment: It wasn't letting me run both functions in the file. the answer saw I was missing a comma after my browser action one. it was trying to end when there was more to read, I forgot the comma to extend it. Boy do I love JS and all the silly stuff I have to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't write a comment,

Perhaps a comma is missing here

```
"default_popup": "popup.html"
 }, <-- HERE!!
"content_scripts":
```

Comment: @M3diik you know when you unpack the chrome extension you can see the error your receiving in extensions window for the manifest and  the console window for any bug

Comment: @johnny5 I know, but I didn't understand what it meant. It didn't say "missing comma", all it said was it was expecting a '}'.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot its shitty like that sometimes.  It also only accepts json with double quotes as a heads up